# The repeating command block gives me a new bow when I try to shoot. How to fix that?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a Minecraft map and I don't want the player to be able loose his bow. So I wrote this command into a repeating command block:

`/replaceitem entity @p hotbar.0 bow{display:{Name:"{"text":"Bow of Shadows","color":"green","italic":"false","bold":"false"}"},"Enchantments":[{id:"minecraft:infinity",lvl:1}]} 1`.

But if I try to shoot an arrow the bow reloads instantly because the command block gives me a new bow and I can't shoot. I have same problem with a shield.

I'm playing Vanilla 1.13.2

Comment: Why are you playing 1.13.2? That version has a lot of game-breaking and world-corrupting bugs and lag issues that were fixed in later versions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the bow is being replaced every tick.

Instead of constantly replacing their first hotbar slot, simply give them a bow if they are missing one.

Instead of the nearest player, we're going to run this as all players for multiplayer support.

```
/execute as @a...
```

First, we need to check if the player has the bow in their inventory:

```
...unless entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:bow", tag:{INSERT NBT}}]}]...
```

Then give them the bow.

```
...run give @p minecraft:bow{INSERT NBT} 1
```

Combine the three lines like this:

```
/execute as @a unless entity @s[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:bow", tag:{INSERT NBT}}]}] run give @s minecraft:bow{INSERT NBT}]} 1
```

This will give every player a Bow of Shadows, if they do not already have a matching bow in their inventory. (replace "INSERT NBT" with the bow's display and enchantment data.)

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can use `/execute as @a[nbt=!{...}]` to simplify the command a bit.

Comment: Thank you but it doesnt work. The command works but the bow get replaced also now.
Did I something wrong?
command is: /execute as @p[nbt=!{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Bow of Shadows\",\"color\":\"green\",\"italic\":\"false\",\"bold\":\"false\"}"},"Enchantments":[{id:"minecraft:infinity",lvl:1}]}] run replaceitem entity @p hotbar.0 bow{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Bow of Shadows\",\"color\":\"green\",\"italic\":\"false\",\"bold\":\"false\"}"},"Enchantments":[{id:"minecraft:infinity",lvl:1}]} 1
(Its a singelplayer map and there are four kits so it doesnt work in multiplayer because everyone would g

Comment: With that command, you're executing it as the nearest player who isn't a Bow of Shadows, so, everyone. Either use the command in the original answer, or replace the `@p[nbt=!{...}]`. Instead of having the bow's NBT data replacing the `...`, use the players NBT data, which can be found in the second code snippet within my original answer. Replace `@p[nbt=!{...}]` with `@p[nbt=!{Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:bow", tag:{INSERT NBT}}]}]`, and replace `INSERT NBT` with the NBT of the bow.